# migrating from mac sdk 10.4u to sdk9

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, sdk

I have upgraded my os from mac 10.7 to mac 10.9 and installed a new xcode 6.0.1 in the new os.
I have a code which is running in xcode 3.2.5 along with 10.4usdk.

do we have any procedure to upgrade from 10.4u sdk to 10.9 sdk?

```
[m_SDMPort setDelegate:self] ==> throws error
```

`// throws error "cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<NSPortDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 'AppMainController *'`

how to avoid this error and these kind of errors while porting from 10.4u sdk to 10.9?

changed the following things.

1. copied the SDK from xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer to  /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk

Under the xcode project

2. changed the OS X Deployment Target as 10.9
3. changed the base SDK as OS x 10.9
4. changed the user defined SDK as /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk
5. changed the project settings, project save format

Comment: Things change and Apple is quick to deprecate methods in favour of others.  There will be so many changes between 10.4 and 10.9 that it's impossible to answer "how to avoid this error and these kind of errors while porting".  Therefore take each issue one-at-a-time.  Voting to close as "too broad".

Comment: I agreed apple has changed a lot, now i'm facing the above error. Can you help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say your error is that `AppMainController` doesn't conform to the `NSPortDelegate` protocol.

Comment: how to make it conform?

Comment: I'm really new to this type of change, if you have any syntax kindly help me out

Comment: @Saravana The Apple documentation can explain it to you better than me.